# Getting Values From XML With Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have below XML file.

```
<Root>
  <r1>
    <n1>Person1</n1>
    <n2>Type1</n2>
  </r1>
  <r1>
    <n1>Person1</n1>
    <n2>Type2</n2>
  </r1>
  <r1>
    <n1>Person2</n1>
    <n2>Type2</n2>
  </r1>
  <r1>
    <n1>Person2</n1>
    <n2>Type3</n2>
  </r1>
  <r1>
    <n1>Person2</n1>
    <n2>Type4</n2>
  </r1>
  <r1>
    <n1>Person2</n1>
    <n2>Type4</n2>
  </r1>
</Root>
```

What I want is to get Types based on Persons. For example I tried below query expecting Type1 and Type2 values for person1 but it did not work.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XML_Document);

XElement[] pages = doc
    .Descendants("r1")
    .OrderBy(x => x.FirstNode.Value=="person1")
    .ToArray();
```

Which query I should use to get it? Or is there a better way to deal with XML documents in asp.net C#?

Comment: I think you should replace your `OrderBy` by `GroupBy(x => x.FirstNode.Value)`

Comment: I've just realized I used orderby there :) I changed it to groupby but it still does not work. it says (operator == cannot be applied to operands of type method group and string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Where()` to filter `r1` by `n1` child element value, and then use `Select()` to return the corresponding `n2` element value :

```
string[] types = doc.Descendants("r1")
                     .Where(x => (string)x.Element("n1") == "person1")
                     .Select(x => (string)x.Element("n2"))
                     .ToArray();
```

And add `Distinct()` after `Select()` if you want to explicitly remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

Try using where statement like below which would give you two xelements

```
        XElement[] pages = doc.Descendants("r1")
                              .Where(x => x.Element("n1").Value == "Person1")
                              .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code:

```
var pages = doc.
            Descendants("r1").
            Where(r1 => r1.Element("n1").Value == "person1").
            Select(r1 => r1.Element("n2").Value).
            ToArray();
```